# why my youtube embedded jwplayer onseek event doesn't work at my website (jwplayer7)

Tags: youtube, jwplayer, jwplayer7

My website use jwplayer embedded both self-host video and youtube video,

pause,play event works fine on both case, however seek even can only catch by self-host video .

The two cases are using the same code.

Can somebody tell me what can i do to fix it?

here is my code:

```
playerInstance = jwplayer("player");
playerInstance.setup({
  modes: [
    file: '<{$youtuve_url}>',
    width: $('#video').width(),
    height: $('#video').height(),
    autostart: false
});

playerInstance.on('seek',function(event){
    console.log("seek");
} );
```

Comment: Do you have a link? Chances are you using an old player version that uses an old YouTube API integration though.

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer i had tried
   link :  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ylLzyHk54Z0
which is a example schema and it still not work

Comment: I mean a link to where you player embed code is running on your site.

Comment: well i decided to use youtube api directly
despite this issue i find out that the subtitle can't be used directly by jwplayer and change rate function will have some other code to compose

Comment: It would be nice if you could have shown an actual example.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the `modes:[`

```
playerInstance = jwplayer("player");
playerInstance.setup({
   file: '<{$youtuve_url}>',
    width: $('#video').width(),
    height: $('#video').height(),
    autostart: false
});

playerInstance.on('seek',function(event){
    console.log("seek");
} );
```

Comment: hey @zer00ne i tried to delete the modes attribute and it still not work,
and all the rest event are work correctly .
Is there any other possible thing i can fix it?

thanks :)

Comment: @張軒銘 Try testing events here: [Basic API](http://qa.jwplayer.com/support-demos/basic-api.html)

Comment: Do you think Is there a possible this is a bug of jwplayer?
if it is caused by my player configuration , the self-host video seek event should be wrong too.

Comment: Did you try using the source of that test page and modify it for your situation? You could compare the video setup to your own and see if there's a difference.